# Understanding iBeacon region monitoring latency and testing

Tags: ios, background, ibeacon, region-monitoring

In order to test region monitoring I have added some **UILocalNotifications** that gets triggered when the app is launched. I have also enabled **background mode** communicates with BLE accessories for the App I am using to test this.

Now, what I have observed is that it does not always get launched with the same time ranges (as Apple's documentation already anticipates there will be a certain latency to avoid false positives). However I am trying to test the overall iBeacon region monitoring reliability and for this reason I drafted some basic test cases:

**Case 1:**

1. Phone is switched off AND beacon is turned on (App is not running).
2. Phone is switched on

Expected result: I expect iOS to wake up app.

Actual result: this does **not always happen immediately**. It does after long long time (e.g. 20 minutes). Is there an **official upper limit for this**?

---

**Case 2:**

1. Phone is on AND beacon is turned off (App is not running).
2. Beacon is turned on

Expected result: I expect iOS to wake up app.

Actual result: It does usually happen.

---

**Case 3:**

1. Phone is on AND beacon is turned off (App is not running).
2. Beacon is turned on
3. Wait until app is woken up (background running).
4. Turn beacon off.
5. Wait until region is exited.
6. Kill App (whilst running in background).
7. Turn beacon on.
8. Wait until App is woken up (background running).

The above flow usually works. However I noticed that it works well when we wait until 5 occurs (region is exited and this event is detected by the app running in background).

---

Any suggestion or further use cases? I struggle in particular with case 1.

Comment: AFAIK, there's no official statement as to how much it might take to re-initialize monitoring after a reboot, Apple rarely shares such implementation details.